# scss error: Argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color

Tags: vue.js, sass, element

I try to build my own theme. i change theme color  to my style. but i got error when compile my own program.

```
:root {
  --color-primary: #409EFF;
}

$--color-primary: var(---color-primary, --color-primary);
$--color-primary-light-1: mix($--color-success, $--color-primary, 10%) !default; /* 53a8ff */
```

error message

```
$--color-primary: var(---color-primary, --color-primary)
```

$--color-primary-light-1: mix($--color-success, $--color-primary, 10%) !default; /* 53a8ff */

how to fix this error, what wrong with my code.

Comment: error   Argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color

Answer (score 0):

```
$--color-primary-light-1: mix($--color-success, #{$--color-primary}, 10%) !default;
```